# What are some pros and cons of parallel podManagementPolicy over OrderedReady podManagementPolicy in StatefulSets?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, microservices, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

I have recently updated podManagementPolicy field in my StatefulSet from default(OrderedReady) to Parallel.

- It has significantly reduced the scale-up and scale-down time.
- I have not seen any downsides of this change as of now, but I am worried if there can be any scenario where it might create problems for me?

I wanted to know if there is any case where i can face any issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to expand on this topic a bit.

The [`OrderedReady` pod management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#orderedready-pod-management) behaves as follows:

- For a StatefulSet with N replicas, when Pods are being deployed, they are created sequentially, in order from {0..N-1}.
- When Pods are being deleted, they are terminated in reverse order, from {N-1..0}.
- Before a scaling operation is applied to a Pod, all of its predecessors must be Running and Ready.
- Before a Pod is terminated, all of its successors must be completely shutdown.

While the [`Parallel` pod management](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#parallel-pod-management):

> tells the StatefulSet controller to launch or terminate all Pods in
> parallel, and to not wait for Pods to become Running and Ready or
> completely terminated prior to launching or terminating another Pod.
> This option only affects the behavior for scaling operations. Updates
> are not affected.

Theoretically you will not face any downtime while updating your app as `parallel` strategy only affects the scaling operations. As already said by Jonas it is hard to foresee the potential consequences without knowing much about your app and architecture. But generally it is safe to say that if your app's instances does not depend on each other (and thus does not have to wait for each pod to be Running and Ready) the `parallel` strategy should be safe and quicker than the `OrderedReady` one. However, if you possibly face any issues with your `StatefulSet` in the future and would like to analyze it from the Kubernetes side, these [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-stateful-set/) might be helpul for you.

Answer (score 6):

> What are some pros and cons of parallel podManagementPolicy over OrderedReady podManagementPolicy in StatefulSets?

This totally depends on your application. Does it need ordered instance scale-up and scale-down?

If you share what application you are using, it is easier to tell if it tolerate that the instances scale-up or down in a specific order.

E.g. a distributed database - that replicates data to its instances - might run with 3 instances - then you want to scale-up to 5 - *but* it takes time to replicate data to those *two new instaces* - and you migth regret scaling up. In this case it is preferred to scale down the two instances that are *not yet* fully replicated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.My Application is not a distributed database. It communicates with the database(redis) to fetch configurations and then starts its processing.

Comment: Your app probably contain some for of _state_ since you use `StatefulSet` - if the instances communicate with eachother - it depens what your app requires. But if the instances are relatively independent - parallel should be fine.